# Is there a way to use async-await or to hold the execution stack while data is returned from subscription

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

I have a function which calls a function inside which in turn subscribes to HTTP call. I know subscription won't return a promise which async await expects but is there a way I can restrict the execution until data is returned.

I have tried using async await but no luck
I can put the code which I want to execute inside the subscription
but I don't want to do that as my function is not made for that (trying to follow Single Responsibility Principle)

```
async function a () {
   await subscription_return();
   code to be executed after subscription has got the data
}

subscription_return(){
     this.http.getDataFromService().subscribe((response) => {});
}
```

Comment: Well you probably shouldn't be subscribing inside the other function. Just return the observable and subscribe in your first function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `await` a promise, like this:

```
async function a () {
   const data = await subscription_return();
   // code to be executed after subscription has got the data
}

subscription_return(){
     return this.http.getDataFromService().toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked,.Just wondering, here while using `http` call we can ensure that the subscription will end after getting data thus we can use toPromise(), but suppose if I had a subscription which never ends, like a click of a button, then how to achieve the above ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can return the `Observable` and use the subscription on require component like in your service.component.ts file contains below-mentioned code.

```
  subscription_return(): Observable<any> {
      return  this.http.getDataFromService();
  }
```

In your actual component, you can subscribe it like

```
this.serviceinstance.subscription_return().subscribe((response) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a general solution for environments where `toPromise` doesn't exist, simply wrap your async call in a promise:

```
async function a () {
   const data = await subscription_return();
   //code to be executed after subscription has got the data
}

subscription_return(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.getDataFromService().subscribe((response) => { resolve(response); });
    });
}
```

demo with a timeout to simulate your async function:

```js
async function a () {
   console.log('start');
   const data = await subscription_return();
   console.log('result: ', data);
}

function subscription_return(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('async done');
            resolve('data');
        }, 100);
    });
}

a();
```